# How can I model the association in the following situation.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following association between entities in the system:

Store
Vendor
and User

- store can have many vendors,
- vendor can belong to multiple stores.
- A user can have multiple stores, but if its a user who is related to vendor, say a person who works for that vendor, then the behavior of that user changes.

Also, for a store there can be multiple roles.

I tried polymorphic association, but since the behavior of the user changes depending on roles and whether he is a store user or a vendor user, I cannot use that.

STI can also not be used since a vast amount of columns will differ. Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: How this is possible "vendor can belong to multiple stores" ?

Comment: belongs to only apply when you store other table id in table as a foreign key

Comment: you need many to many relationship between store  and vendors ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your requirements accurately you want to model:

- A vendor can have many stores
- A store can have many vendors
- A vendor can have many users
- A store can have many users

That would require a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between vendor and store. It would also require a polymorphic association between user and vendor/store. You *should* be able to use a polymorphic association. That way you could manage system behaviour for each user by checking their roles and associations. If you created a polymorphic association named `userable` for example, you could user `user.userable` to get either the vendor or the store and `vendor.users` or `store.users` to access users for those instances.

Answer (score 0):

For your user model, regarding this line in your question:

*"but if its a user who is related to vendor, say a person who works for that vendor, then the behavior of that user changes"*

I would add a column to my user table called `user_type` and create some user types that you can use to filter out and assign privileges to. The `user_type` column could be a string field and explicitly named something like `related` and `not_related`, simply an integer 1 or 2, or more, or even a boolean field if there aren't going to be too many `user_types`.